# Inversibility of an almost skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that given a skew-symmetrix matrix $L$, the matrix $I-L$ is invertible (by computing its spectrum, which doesn't contain zero). Suppose now that instead of a skew-symmetrix matrix $L$, we have a matrix $L+D$ with $L$ skew-symmetric and $D$ diagonal. Does somebody know if $I-(L+D)$ is invertible?

Comment: What if $L=0$ and $D=I$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the field is real. The sum of a diagonal matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix can be singular or non-singular. E.g. $\pmatrix{1/k&-1\\ 1&-k}$ is singular but $\pmatrix{k&-1\\ 1&k}$ is non-singular for any real $k$.

However, if $I-D$ is a positive or negative diagonal matrix, then $I-D+L$ must be non-singular for any skew-symmetric, because the equation $(I-D+L)x=0$ has only the trivial solution: $(I-D+L)x=0$ implies that $x^T(I-D)x=x^T(I-D+L)x=0$, which in turn implies that $x=0$.